# Beanshell type of variable assertion on Jmeter

Tags: scripting, jmeter, assertion, beanshell, variable-types

I want to validate some variable types from a response on Jmeter by using Beanshell Assertions like so

(C# example)

```
if(foo typeof bar){
   //stuff
}
```

I've googled and searched on beanshell documentation but i can't find anything close to this.

Is there a way to do something simmilar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for an [`instanceof`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instanceof) operator?

```
foo ="1";

if (foo instanceof String) {
   log.info("It's a string");
}

foo = 1;

if (foo instanceof bsh.Primitive) {
   log.info("It's a primitive");
}
```

[image]

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth migrating to [JSR223 Assertion and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: This is what i needed. Thank you so much.